# Fill a hole in a 2x4

Tags: hole, filling

Building a Cornhole board I drilled hole to bolt legs in.  I can’t remove the boards due to all pieces glued and screwed together.  How do I fill the holes I drilled for the legs ?

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the hole isn't visible, you can squirt a little wood glue into the hole and then push a cocktail stick into it and break it off flush (ish) with the surface, repeat with more sticks until it's nice and full. You might need to tap the last one in with something like a small hammer. Leave until the glue sets and then trim up the top. Saves buying a long length of dowel.

Alternatively, if you have a good knife or chisel, fashion yourself a little wooden plug and glue it in the same. Let dry and saw off afterwards.